# Creating iOS page indicator (dots) with jQuery Mobile

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, carousel

**// my Question to the lovely lady in the corner** 

I would like to create a pagination for indicating what page is visible, like in iOS, (those little dots below a window, known as "page indicators" in the HIG.)

[image: chunky bacon]

-- My project is hereby referred to as, Her Highness.

**I found an example, but I can't find documentation on re-creating the layout, and it's in the experiment section :(**
http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/#../../docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

Comment: My first lead: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/#../../docs/toolbars/index.html

Comment: It seems the solution is: 1. Create a persistent footer 2. Go to sleep

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure why this is the part that seems hard to you, but if you're talking about how to make circles with html/css3, then I've got a simple answer. Just make your dots with a border radius equal to half the height/width.

```
<span class="dot dot1"></span>
<span class="dot dot2"></span>
<span class="dot dot3"></span>
<span class="dot dot4"></span>
```

...

```
.dot {
    display: inline-block;
    width:12px;height:12px;
    border-radius:6px;
    background-color:#8999A6;
}
.page4 .dot4 {
    background-color: white;
}
```

If you can't figure out what to do beyond that, you're going to basically need someone to do the whole thing for you, but I'll give you a hint. Somewhere higher up, you're going to set a class indicating the active page. That will allow you to trigger CSS rules that could say which matching dot is active, and change the bg to white.

Comment: You're right, but for some reason I feel there's a much better, correct way of indicating the number of local pages in a window than putting a physical image or css shape in the local page itself. But it would work, you're correct.

Comment: It's html dude, the abstractions live in how you generate it. If you prefer, you could use Canvas or SVG as a background image, but I doubt its  going to make your code seem more elegant.

Comment: I'm not arguing that it shouldn't be marked up like you're creating it, in fact, what you're making is already helpful to me, but I don't want that HTML in the same divs that are being swiped. **I'm vain,** I want a good user experience, wouldn't it be weird to see a whole new row of dots slide in, instead of changing one dot at a time?

Comment: And see, the whole time, I was already assuming it would be in a persistent footer.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the discussion under Russel's answer I think I understand what You want.

1. Create a presistent footer. That's not a trivial thing to do, but can be done. 
   You can take a look at my plugin for two column layouts http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/dualColumn.html
   or wait for me to take your issue into account while I work on it during the weekend (,which I advise you to :P).
2. After you got the presistent footer you can generate the dots from the list of pages and then handle a `pageshow` event to highlight the correct dot.

Wrapping the whole thing in a widget code would allow it to be a progressive enhancement, not a messy pile of code that would iritate users with nonAgrade browsers.

Comment: Persistent footers; imagine the tabs on the bottom as simply page indicators. http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/#../../docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

Comment: Get the code and you're ready :D Just generate the dots and change their classes with `pageshow` handler

Comment: Get the code and you're ready? You should look at the source... good luck.

Comment: I thought you liked the way it was done there. Either way - my answer remains valid. Get the code of my dualColumn plugin and change it a bit to get a presistent footer (in fact you need to change one `before` to `after` and set width parameter to 100%)