# Page Indicator like ios/Android using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 4 or more pages in my web app and i am looking something like page indicator in ios/android. Is it possible now to achieve this using Jquery mobile or some other effective way.

i have found following question regarding the same requirement and so wanted to know if Jquery has introduced page indicator since then or **there is a better effective way to achieve the same now**.

[Creating iOS page indicator (dots) with jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400355/creating-ios-page-indicator-dots-with-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with some pretty simple programming, put 4 dots (you could use images) in the footer and then with javascript you write something like (pseudocode):

```
page = get current page
switch(page) {
    case 1:
        highlight dot1
        -make sure all other dots are not highlighted
    break;
    case 2:
        -highlight dot2
        -make sure all other dots are not highlighted
    break;
    etc...
}
```

I just checked on my iphone and the dot highlightning isn't even animated, so you could just get away with some images or generated dots.